# Angular 6 : HttpHeaders Cannot read property 'length' of null in Chrome and IE11 (and not in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, google-chrome, angular-httpclient

Under my **Angular6** app , i'm using **HttpClient** with some headers injection to my htpp calls to fetch data from my backend server :

***My service :***

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadUserInfosService {

  public _headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getUserPnsInfos(cuid): Observable<object> {
    const headers = this._headers.append('login', login);
    return this.httpClient.get(myBackUrl, {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

**My component where i'm subscribing to it :**

```
loadUserInfosFromPns(login) {
    this.loadUserInfosService.getUserPnsInfos(login).subscribe(infos => {
      let receivedInfos: any;
        receivedPnsInfos = infos ;
        console.log(receivedPnsInfos);
        if (pnsInfos !== null && receivedPnsInfos.cuid === cuid ) {
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['unauthorized'], {skipLocationChange: true});
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

when running on Chrome or IE11 i'm getting some error refering to my request headers:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:199)
    at http.js:170
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init (http.js:170)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:235)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1445)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:161)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:127)
```

this error appears only in **Chrome** and **IE11** - while under **Firefox** the ***request get well and i'm not getting it***

**Any ideas , suggestions ?**

Comment: What kind of value hold the `login` variable (which does not seem to be declared)? And what if you use `append` instead of `set` ?

Comment: it s a string : example : "fczb1938"

Comment: @David same thing for set and append : it goes well with Firefox but not in chrome and IE11

Answer (score 12):

It is probably caused because you are settting an undefined / null header in some http request.

Comment: I had the same problem, and your solution helped me! thank you a lot

Comment: I was not able to find the issue causing this problem. Your answer was the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem but when refresh page, I was hit the require API and this issue I have resolved by referring some of the examples and add the below lines to httpClient(http:httpClient)

> ```
>  return this.http.get('url, {header}).pipe(
>         retry(1), catchError(this.handleError)
>       )
> ```

**retry and catch** error are imported from **rxjs operator**

> **import { catchError, map, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';**

**handleError** is the function to handle the error

This resolve the error for me