# Angular6 HttpClient : Inject Headers on Get request is not working on Chrome and IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-cli-v6

Unde rmy **Angular 6** app , i am trying use some **GET** request , while injecting some **Headers** :

***My service*** looks like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
}
getUserInfos(cuid): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'login': login});
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.urls.UserHabilitation, {headers});
}
```

***Within my Component : I'm subscribing to it like the following :***

```
this.myService.getUserInfos(login).subscribe(infos => {
      console.log(infos );
      error => {
        console.log(error);
});
```

It works well under **Firefox** , **but not under Chrome and IE11** ; and i got such ann error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate
>   (http.js:199)
>       at http.js:170
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init
>   (http.js:170)
>       at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach
>   (http.js:235)
>       at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1445)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:42)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:28)
>       at subscribeTo.js:21
>       at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 : HttpHeaders Cannot read property 'length' of null in Chrome and IE11 (and not in Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323979/angular-6-httpheaders-cannot-read-property-length-of-null-in-chrome-and-ie11)

Comment: Probably not the case, but could it be that your variable is empty?https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18743

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your '}' is in the wrong place. Subscribe can get 2 arguments, the execution and the error response:

```
this.myService.getUserInfos(login).subscribe(
      infos => {
        console.log(infos);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
);
```

Or shorter:

```
this.myService.getUserInfos(login).subscribe(
      infos => console.log(infos ),
      error => console.log(error)
);
```